# How are do you handle dependencies for nested components in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

## I'm running into this error:

```
browser_adapter.js:76 Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for NestedComponent(undefined). Make sure they all have valid type or annotations.
    at NoAnnotationError.BaseException [as constructor]
```

## Here's the breakdown:

I have a service

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    doSomething() {
        console.log("This is a service, and it's doing stuff");
    }
}
```

That can be injected into components, like this, without issue:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent-component',
    template: '<p>This works great!</p>',
    providers: [MyService]
})
export class ParentComponent {
    constructor(private _myService: MyService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this._myService.doSomething();
    }
}
```

I have problems, however, when I try to inject the service into nested components, like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'nested-component',
    template: "<p>This doesn't work. :(</p>",
    providers: [MyService]
})
export class NestedComponent {
    constructor(private _myService: MyService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this._myService.doSomething();
    }
}
```

When I try to plug the nested component into the parent component, I get the error up there ^. How can I achieve this.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent-component',
    template: '<nested-component></nested-component>',
    directives: [NestedComponent]
})
export class ParentComponent {
}
```

For what it's worth, I still run into that error, even when I include MyService in the bootstrap function of my app:

```
function main() {
  return bootstrap(App, [
    // These are dependencies of our App
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    MyService,
    ELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS // remove in production
  ])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share single instance of service,
***dont use***,

```
providers: [MyService]
```

in each component. 
Look into this example which doesn't use `providers:[...]` ,
[`shared instance`, `not providers used`, `registered into bootstrap`](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZoojV2SiQBqxAJhxGxyW?p=preview)

And if you don't want to share,
***remove*** ,

```
providers: [MyService]
```

from nested-component. 

Look into this example which  uses `providers:[...]`,
[`not shared instance`, `not registered into bootstrap`, `used with providers in parent only and not in child`,](http://plnkr.co/edit/uPb0eHXPke41zSa9IBdS?p=preview)

Comment: In my example, I've only added the `providers` property to the component using the service (notice its removal from `ParentComponent` when it is being injected into `NestedComponent`).

Comment: Reading your answer again : "if you want to share a single instance remove MyService" "If you *don't* want to share remove MyService" < Seems to be a logical conflict here ... or maybe I'm misreading?

Comment: @drewwyatt.Do you want to share instance among components?

Comment: @basarat Yes, I would like to share an instance between components, but the problem is the error I am receiving. That error appears whether `MyService` is added to providers for `ParentComponent`, `NestedComponent`, the bootstrap function, all, or none of the above.

Comment: If you want to share instance among components, simply inject it into bootstrap function and then only use `import {service}....` in each component. don't use `providers:[service]` in each component.

Comment: @micronyks this still throws the above error when `NestedComponent` is added to `directives` in `ParentComponent`

Comment: check now.. i have given you example.

Comment: @micronyks For your example to be accurate,`thecontent` should be a child of `navbar`.

Comment: @micronyks actually... you are right. after forking your example - I see there is a problem with my app. your logic is correct.